# long String in a paragraph without break the full characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is that possible to make a long string like below come in next line(in a paragraph) and not breaking the characters in a long/short string? If long string comes, then the full string need to go next line. (Not half words in first line, and remaining half in next line.)

currently it is showing like this,

> My sample text **ha**
>   **s** errors as it is
>  displaying a long
>  strings in next **l**
>   **ine** with breaking
>   the word.

I need like this,

> My sample text **has**
>  no errors as it is
>  displaying a
>   **long**
>  strings in next 
>  line with breaking 
>  the word.

Kindly give me any example in jsfiddle or any thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code so far, and an example that fails to reproduce the particular issue you're having. We don't give away free codez here.

Comment: This should be the default behaviour, or can be achieved using `word-wrap:normal`

Comment: Hi elclanrs, thanks a lot for your help.. On the way to edit, you changed.. so many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 word-break: keep-all;
```

instead of

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: by applying keep-all, there were no reflection in the paragraph.

Comment: can you provide, sample in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi its working fine by your ideas... thanks for your wonderful suggestions.